# How to update Area path for a team using the Azure DevOps API

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the Azure DevOps API to update a teams area/classification node.

[image]

However I am unable to find the API to do this.

I was able update the **teams iteration** using the API (see image below). But couldn't find nothing for setting a Teams default Area path.

[image]

I've pressed F12 and looked at the payload when manually setting the teams area path, but this did not point me to an API either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update team areas you can use `Teamfieldvalues`:

1. Get current settings: [Get team field values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/teamfieldvalues/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples)
2. Update team settings: [Update team field values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/teamfieldvalues/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-team-field-values.-example-1)